# REST API design for updating the parent of a node in tree hierarchy

Tags: rest, api, url, restful-url

I have three database tables with the below structure:

```
Country
id | name  

State
id | name | country_id

City
id | name | state_id
```

The existing REST endpoint URLs for these are:

```
/country                                                For list of all countries
/country/{country_id}                                   For a specific country
/country/{country_id}/state                             For list of all states in a country
/country/{country_id}/state/{state_id}                  For a specific state
/country/{country_id}/state/{state_id}/city             For list of all the cities in a state of a country
/country/{country_id}/state/{state_id}/city/{city_id}   For a specific city
```

Now I have a requirement to move one city from one state to the other, how should I design the REST Endpoint for this operation? Suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a requirement to move one city from one state to the other, how should I design the REST Endpoint for this operation?

As far as I can tell, there isn't a great answer here.

A commonly useful heuristic is to think about how you would do this on a web site: you would load some form, use the input controls to describe your changes, submit the form, and the http client would `POST` the form data to some URI specified by the server.

So that part is straight forward enough - the URI can be "anything" because the client doesn't care; it is just going to use the URI in the form.

The server will receive the message and process it.  Side effects that change other resources are possible, at the server's discretion, so that's all right.

But the caching story isn't very good.  The semantics of the request to "move" a city changes the representations of the source state, the target state, perhaps also the city itself.  We can arrange the form so that any one of these resources is invalidated by the successful response (simply by using that identifier as the target of the request), but we don't have any standardized mechanism for invalidating the other resources.

If the entire tree hierarchy were described by a single resource, then there would be no issue - that would be the one resource we invalidate.

(Imagine wikipedia - you make a change to the page for `Boston`, and that also changes the page for `Massachusetts`.  There's no standard way to tell the client that *both* pages changed.)